# Por que está dando o erro string indices must be integers?

Tags: python

Sou iniciante em python

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico, chamando a função:

```
def plota_grafico(sistema, resultado, r, variavel)
```

Como possuo poucas variáveis criei blocos de if dependendo da escolha da variável. Todos eles funcionam corretamente, exceto o bloco a seguir:

```
  if variavel == 'CMO':
for i, iusi in enumerate(resultado["DGer"]):
  plt.plot(x+1, iusi['CMO'], marker='d')
plt.title('Evolução do Custo Marginal de Operação ($)')
plt.xlabel('Período ou Mês de Planejamento')
plt.ylabel('Custo Marginal de Operação ($)')
plt.xticks(x+1)
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
```

O erro marca a terceira linha. Se necessário, compartilho o resto do código. Porém ele é extenso, possui outras funções além da plotagem.

Comment: Parece que você está tentando montar um dashboard, eu aconselho a compartilhar o dataset e o código que você está utilizando. Você postou o erro mas não postou em qual linha pode estar ocorrendo, dessa forma é complicado ajudar.

Comment: Realmente, tem pouca informação rs. Sou novata aqui também. Já consegui resolver. Mas muito obrigada pela disposição em ajudar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro é gerado quando tenta-se acessar uma posição em uma string utilizando outra string ([vide link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077692/12114971)). Como strings não são dicionários, apenas números inteiros podem ser utilizados como índice, retornando a respectiva letra daquela posição.

Não tenho muitos detalhes, então imagino que a variável `iusi` possa ser (ou conter um valor que seja) uma string, e quando você executa `iusi['CMO']`, gera o erro, pois tenta-se acessar uma posição indexada por 'CMO' nessa string.

Comment: Obrigada! Consegui entender o erro. As outras variáveis estavam escritas de maneira diferente. ‘CMO’ é uma lista dentro de um dicionário, e eu estava apontando pra key do dicionário em vez de apontar pra lista quando usava o for e o enumerate. Foi só tirar o for e colocar (resultado[“DGer”][“CMO”]) diretamente na posição dos dados do eixo y que deu certo.